# Changing Excel Report Name in REST

Tags: java, excel, file, rest, report

I have the following method which generate an excel report:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/class/{classid}/absent/getstudentreport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void studentreport(@PathVariable String classid, HttpServletResponse response) {
Workbook workBook = studentDetailService.getStudentActivityReport(new Long(classid));   //DAO call
    try {
         writeReport(workBook,response); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

writeReport contains the following:

```
    private void writeReport(Workbook workBook,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=cp1252");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    OutputStream sOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    workBook.write(sOutputStream);
    sOutputStream.flush();
}
```

Every time i hitting the url:

```
  http://localhost:8087/class/123/absent/getstudentreport
```

It is downloading a report with **getstudentreport.xls**, i want to change the report name something like this:
            **student_absent_mm_dd_yy_hh_mm_ss.xls** where (mm,dd,yy are month, day and year resp and hh,mm,ss are hour minute and sec resp)

How can i do that. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your file name in

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"");
```

something like this

```
response.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=student_absent_mm_dd_yy_hh_mm_ss.xls");
```

Please note that in order to name file as 'student_absent_mm_dd_yy_hh_mm_ss.xls'. you have to write logic using

```
Date or Calendar
```

by extracting/formatting datetime object.